# How to define routes with multiple parameters without pretty urls in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, dynamic-url

I am using Laravel. I would like users to be able to perform a search on my website using up to 3 criteria. These criteria are: Class, Brand and Model.

They should be free to use any or all of them when searching. As the relationship between these isn't as simple as Many->1, Many->1, Many->1, and also given the criteria will be numbered if blank, I dont want to use pretty urls to post the search criteria as they would look like this:

```
/SearchResults/0/BMW/0
```

which is meaningless to users and search engines. I therefore want to use normal dynamic addresses for this route as follows:

```
/SearchResults/?Class=0&Brand="BMW"&Model=0
```

How do I define a route that allows me to extract these three criteria and pass it to a custom method in my resource controller?

I have tried this but it isnt working:

```
Route::get('/SearchResults/?Class={$class}&Brand={$brand}&Model={$type}', 'AdvertController@searchResults');
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony Routing components fetch the `REQUEST_URI` server variable for matching routes, and thus Laravel's `Route` Facade would not pick up URL parameters.

Instead, make use of `Input::get()` to fetch them.

For example, you would start by checking if the `class` param exists by using `Input::has('class')`, and then fetching it with `Input::get('class')`. Once you have all three, or just some of them, you'd start your model/SQL query so that you may return your results to the user.

Comment: That makes sense - Im happy to retrieve the params this way, but I still need to route to the correct class method - how would I do this while ignoring the params?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you would only need to map the `SearchResults` route to your `AdvertController@SearchResults` method. The parameters will be available there anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to route all to the same method and then, within the controller, reroute that given action to the correct method within the controller.

For that, I recommend using the strategy pattern ([read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)).

I would do something like this:

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/SearchResults', 'AdvertController@searchResults');
```

**AdvertController.php**

```
use Input;
...
private $strategy = [];
public function __construct(){
    $strategy = [
        /*class => handler*/
        '0'=> $this->class0Handler,
        '1'=>$this->class1Handler,
        ...];
}
private function class0Handler(){
    //your handler method
}
public function searchResults(){
    if( !array_key_exists(Input::get('class'),$this->strategy))
        abort(404);
    return $this->strategy[Input::get('class')]();
}
```

In case you are breaking down search by other types, you define the handler in the `$strategy` variable.

Strategy pattern has a lot of benefits. I would strongly recommend it.